# Setup Sharepoint 2010 development machines

Tags: hyper-v, sharepoint-2010, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I'm currently assigned to the task of preparing our development machines for a SharePoint 2010 project.

The machines are quite beefy:

- 1x Intel Core i7 950 with 16GB
- 2x Intel Core i7 950 with 12GB

**Software**

- SharePoint 2010
- Enterprise SQL Server
- 2008 R2 Windows 2008 R2

The development machines should be as identical as possible. And I want to use Hyper-V, so I can easily re-use the images (install one machine, and copy images) and be a little more flexible.

I have read a couple of install guides. And most of the time they are installing on a laptop with VM (VMWware), and/or installing all components (SQL, AD, SharePoint) in one virtual machine.

The question I'd like to ask is. What components (SQL, AD, SharePoint) should go where in order to have the same setup on all three machines. Since all three machines are running in the same network, I don't think running three "the same" DC's.

One scenario I thought of is:

**Machine 1:**
VM1 : 1 Active Directory/Domain Controller (Windows 2008 R2 - Core)
VM2 : SQL Server + SharePoint

**Machine 2 + 3:**
VM1 : SQL Server + SharePoint
Machine 2 + 3 point to Machine 1/VM1 as their AD/DC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having only one shared DC is the way to go, so your proposal sounds fine to me.

If you are going to try any performance related tasks, you may also want to consider deploying SQL Server to a separate dedicated machine.

A final consideration. You have 12GB and 16GB of RAM on your respective machines. This will be fine in your configuration, although there will not be much capacity for extra Hyper-V instances in the future. (Assuming each machine runs SQL Server, SharePoint 2010 and Visual Studio 2010)